# New to Sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: site-template

I was searching for the problem that I am getting once I am trying to edit the form in sharepoint designer 2013. The instruction was about to go to web server extension and to template. However there is no template folder under 14 folder? is that something I should make it or the admin or how it works? any help is appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For 2013, you need to go in to the `15` folder **on the server**, found here

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15
```

There you'll find the `TEMPLATE` folder

(There should be on in the `14` folder too though..)

Comment: Robert. Thank you for your reply, and sorry if I posted my comment in the wrong place not sure why it was deleted.  I appreciate your help I really need it. I did go to folder 15 per your instruction but I cannot find folder template there. Just the BIN. I also have a question that I am unable to open my site from sharepoint designer 2013 and I am getting a message saying that web configured contact your web amin. Now can you direct me what to do and how to fix this issue please? thank you indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referencing to SharePoint filesytem which you can't access from SPD.

You should open the drive in SharePoint server and traverse to

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions
```

Now you can choose `14` hive and then `Template`